# How to maximize Window to Left/Right Half Screen?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, shortcut

I was using Ubuntu 12.04, the shortcut Ctrl+Window+Left Arrow/Right Arrow is to move and zoom current window to left and right, now I switch to Fedora 20 and CANNOT find the shortcuts, is there anyone know how to set this hotkey?

For example, the following are the shortcuts in Ubuntu, I want to know the how to make it work in Fedora:

Maximize left/right/fullscreen = Ctrl+WindowsButton+(left/right/up arrow)

Move Window to different workspace = shift+Ctrl+alt+(arrows)

Swich workspace = ctrl+alt+(arrows)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like the "View split on left" and "View split on right" settings in Fedora 20. By default they're set to [windows key] + [left arrow] and [windows key] + [right arrow]. These will move the window to the left or right such that it takes up half the screen.

You can reconfigure the keyboard shortcuts by going into Settings, Keyboard switching to the Shortcuts tab and going under the Windows category.

Comment: I didnt find anything about  "View split on left" and "View split on right" settings, working on Fedora 20 Mate

Comment: They should be there under the "Windows" category. Here's a reference in the [gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.3/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en). If you're not seeing them it could be because you're not running with [compiz](http://youngfrog.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/view-split-on-rightleft-tile-without-compiz/)